# How can I iterate by row and column in a way that does not require me to specifically name each column?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I am writing an algorithm to analyze an excel file. I need a way to calculate the positive and negative values in each column.

I have tried to make each column a list, and then calculate from there. The main problem I have is the variable size of the data set.

If I upload a file, I want the algorithm to calculate and output by the number of columns in the file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Two-dimensional data frame
table = {'A' : [0.1, -0.2, 0.3, -0.4],'B' : [-0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8], 'C' : [0.3, -0.6, -0.9, -1.3]}

# Setting index to be new column
df = pd.DataFrame(table, index = ['W','X','Y','Z'])

column_list = list(df.columns)
total_columns = len(column_list)

total_rows = len(df.index)

column_num = 1
column = column_list[column_num]
winners = []
losers = []
zero = []   


for col_num in df: 
 row_num = 1
   for row_num in df:
     if (df.iloc[row_num][column]) > 0:
         Winners.append(df.iloc[row_num][column]
         row_num = row_num + 1

     elif (df.iloc[row_num][column]) < 0:
         losers.append(df.iloc[row_num][column])
         row_num = row_num + 1

     else:
         zero.append(df.iloc[row_num][column])
         row_num = row_num + 1

column_num +=1 

df2 = pd.dataframe(winners)
df2['Losers'] = losers
```

Why is it so hard to iterate by each individual column-row?

I want my output to be another Dataframe where I will append more analysis.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the positive values and negative values within each column, this is easy for one column, but I want to automate it for an undetermined number of columns within a dataframe.

Comment: This will let you iterate over a df if you want to do analysis outside of pandas. `for index, row in df.iterrows():`

Comment: See also [iteritems](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html#pandas.DataFrame.iteritems)

Comment: @Marco can you post what your output DataFrame should look like for the example given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own function, which can be as complex as you want and apply it to either rows (axis=1) or columns (axis=0).

In this case I made a simple function that takes in a row, or column (depending on axis) and returns the count of [positive, negative, zero].

With his you get lists back which you can use for your calculations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Two-dimensional data frame
table = {'A' : [0.1, -0.2, 0.3, -0.4],'B' : [-0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8], 'C' : [0.3, -0.6, -0.9, -1.3]}

# Setting index to be new column
df = pd.DataFrame(table, index = ['W','X','Y','Z'])
>>> df
     A    B    C
W  0.1 -0.2  0.3
X -0.2  0.4 -0.6
Y  0.3  0.6 -0.9
Z -0.4  0.8 -1.3

def counts(row):
    # counts
     return [sum(n>0 for n in row), sum(n<0 for n in row), sum(n==0 for n in row)]
    # probabilities
    # total = len(row)
    # return [sum(n>0 for n in row) / total, sum(n<0 for n in row) / total, sum(n==0 for n in row) / total]


>>> df.apply(counts, axis=0)
A    [2, 2, 0]
B    [3, 1, 0]
C    [1, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would give you what you need.  I don't see why you would worry about rows and columns if you're just calculating totals of the entire dataframe.

```
losers = sum(n < 0 for n in df.values.flatten())
winners = sum(n > 0 for n in df.values.flatten())
zero = sum(n==0 for n in df.values.flatten())
```

Comment: I would suggest rephrasing your original post to make it more clear what you want, including a real data sample if the one you are showing isn't realistic.

Comment: Each column gets n-1 smaller as the columns get added.

I need the count of positive and negative values in each column to calculate probabilities in each column.

Answer (score 0):

You can let python iterate the columns and rows for you.

```
for column in df.columns:
   for row_num in df.index:
```

If you leave out an index when you create the dataframe it'll automatically assign it a numeric one - `df = pd.DataFrame(table, index = ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])` vs `df = pd.DataFrame(table)`
if you supply an index just use `for row_num in range(len(df.index)):` instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Two-dimensional data frame
table = {'A' : [0.1, -0.2, 0.3, -0.4],'B' : [-0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8], 'C' : [0.3, -0.6, -0.9, -1.3]}

# Setting index to be new column
df = pd.DataFrame(table)

winners = []
losers = []
zero = []


for column in df.columns:
   for row_num in df.index:
     if (df.iloc[row_num][column]) > 0:
         winners.append(df.iloc[row_num][column])

     elif (df.iloc[row_num][column]) < 0:
         losers.append(df.iloc[row_num][column])

     else:
         zero.append(df.iloc[row_num][column])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(winners)
df2['Losers'] = losers

print(df2)
print(winners)
print(losers)
print(zero)
```